# SQL Server 2005 stored procedure fast in SSMS slow from VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which when run from SQL Server Management Studio consistently takes 5 seconds to run when called like this.

```
exec dbo.MyStoredProc  '2009-04-30 00:00:00', '2009-04-30 20:00:00'
```

When called from an excel spreadsheet via VBA it takes 6 minutes plus (not including the time taken to copy the recordset to a sheet. The VBA is nothing fancy simply using an ADO connection to return a recordset. Unfortunately the Excel approach is a client requirement that I can't get rid of yet.

```
Public Function GenerateSQL(strQueryName As String) As Recordset
Dim rs As Recordset, cm As Command, dbsConn As Connection

Set dbsConn = New ADODB.Connection
dbsConn.Open Configuration.Range("ConnectionString")
Set cm = New ADODB.Command


With cm
    .CommandText = strQueryName
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 300
    .ActiveConnection = dbsConn

    Set rs = .Execute()

End With

Set GenerateSQL = rs
End Function
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen or how I could begin to trace what is happening?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Are you using the exact same parameter values?

Comment: Sorry, one more question - how much data is being returned (roughly) - number of rows and columns (and are any of them particularly big)?

Comment: Can you run SQL profiler and confirm if the sql is the issue or the remains of the macro in excel ?

Comment: According to the code that you have posted, you are not passing any parameter values at all.  This may be causing the stored procedure to run across all source records.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 stored procedure fast in SSMS slow from VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808914/sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-fast-in-ssms-slow-from-vba)

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but if it ends up closed can we make sure it's merged, because of the link in Remus' answer?

Answer (score 8):

Everything you need to know about this topic: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: +1 - Just about anything written by Mr. Sommarskog is worth your time.

Comment: @Joel I more than agree: http://rusanu.com/2011/02/21/erlands-sommarskog-adds-another-gem-to-his-treasure-chest/

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have the same problem as Steve Homer.
In addition to this SO question I also found this thread on eggheadcafe.com [Very slow SP execution when using .net - very fast in Management Studio - totico](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=34233534&threadid=34233534)

The answers say it's about parameter sniffing and how that affects which execution plan is used. The answers there specifically mentions the `arithabort` set option and how that affects the selection of plan.

<strike>Now I just need to find out how to change the set options from VBA...</strike>

Finally thanks to this [forum entry on social.msdn.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/f81fb2a7-5190-40e5-9541-26cb94172230/) i managed to get it right. First, set multiple connections to false:

```
connectionObject.Properties("Multiple Connections") = False
```

and then use the following function on your connection to set arithabort on ...

```
Private Sub OptionSet(ByRef cnn As adodb.Connection)
  Dim cmd As adodb.Command

  Set cmd = New adodb.Command
  With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adodb.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
    .CommandText = "set arithabort on"
    Call .Execute
  End With
  Set cmd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)**

- Set up a trace on your database.
- Limit the trace only to the stored procedure object in question
- Limit to the username used by the VBA code

[An introduction to SQL Server Profiler](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3482216)

In particular, check the [SET options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190707(SQL.90).aspx) used by the connection and compare these with the defaults used when running the stored procedure in SSMS.

I have come across scenarios before where the SET options were different between calling code and within SSMS and the difference in performance was *HUGE*.

Comment: dbcc useroptions <- useful MS SQL query for checking current set options

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I'll take a look at the trace tools.

In reply to the comments on the original question

**Are you using the exact same parameter values?**

Yes exactly the same.

**How much data is being returned (roughly) - number of rows and columns (and are any of them particularly big)?**

Under 200 rows, perhaps 15 fields mostly ints with a couple of 20 character varchars.

**Can you run SQL profiler and confirm if the sql is the issue or the remains of the macro in excel ?**

The SQL is pretty ugly, as is the underlying database schema, and unfortunately is under NDA so I can't post it. If the query were the issue then wouldn't it be slow in management studio too though?

Comment: If you run profiler as you run the code from your vba; it will help you rule out or rule in that the SQL Server is the issue. If Profiler says 2 seconds for your query then the issue is in the script or network rather than the sql server. If it is slow in teh sql server then it gives us something further to consider.