# Slow Query Execution in Profiler/Fast in MMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I made an DB auditing to sort out some performance problems one customers has in a part of our software. I used the profiler to look for the queries that were taking too much time. Minutes later i saw the selects that were taking sooo long to execute (up to minutes). As usual i took the selects and let them execute in the management studio to search for missing or bad indexes (execution plan). 
Then the shock they are blazing fast (milliseconds) and use good indexes.
Now my guess was a locking problem but to my surprise the select has the nolock on both tables marker....
Networkproblems seem not to be the hickup here since i have good times from different clients on other selects (the slow selects come from different clients).
Just to be sure i maintained the indexes on the 2 inner joined tables used in this select without any success. Other selects with those tables don't have those horrible times.
edit: so my not so clear question is what steps should be taken to further look for the problem?

Comment: Is this a *question* or an explanation?

Comment: so sorry i edited the topic

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 stored procedure fast in SSMS slow from VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808914/sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-fast-in-ssms-slow-from-vba)

Comment: See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Which SQL version (and service pack)? There were a few service packs that fixed problems like these, for different versions of SS.

Comment: i read some month ago one lesson applied was to use ARITHABORT = OFF and use the same user. do you have other suggestions? btw this is not from a stored proc. and i wiped the cache manytimes....

Comment: @GBoehm - Fiddling around with `ARITHABORT` is an investigation measure not a fix. For the fix you would need to look at `OPTIMIZE FOR` or `RECOMPILE` hints.

Comment: The Version is 9.00.4230.00 which should be Service Pack 3 of the 2005 Server

Comment: @MartinSmith of course but as soon as i can see the slow execution in my execution plan i will find a sollution but as of now i have no idea why my query gets executed slowly through my application and fast in the management studio.

Comment: @GBoehm - Different execution plans. Probably parameter sniffing. This is all explained in great detail in that article.

Comment: @MartinSmith the query is a select not using sp_executesql

Comment: Well you need to compare the execution plans from both environments. You can get this using Profiler or from the plan cache DMVs. If the plans are the same then you will need to look at wait stats during the slow execution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37596/discussion-between-gboehm-and-martin-smith)

Answer (score 0):

Several questions to answer:

- is your test environement the same as the productive (customer) environment?
- What is the difference between test and prod. Environment (e.g. DB Stats)
- Do you know of concurrent processes running at customer site?
- What about the table volumes (number of records)?
- Key definitions and indexes OK ?
- and many more steps you could take but start with these ones

Comment: i execute the query on the productiv server because i thought about the same problems as you suggested. So same environment